# Search by an object inside an object in AngularJS smart table

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I have got a table which I want to be able to search through. It works great for the quiz title but the course title doesn't seem to work. I know it is because the course title is inside another dictionary, because if I put "course" instead of "course.title" it works, but it searches inside the whole course object instead of just for the title, which I don't want it to. How can I get search for only the course.title? I think it is only a matter of syntax but I can't find a similar problem anywhere.

```
<table  st-table="displayedQuizzes" st-safe-src="quizzes" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th st-sort="quiz.title">Name</th>
            <th st-sort="quiz.course.title">Course</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><input st-search="'title'" class="input-sm form-control" placeholder="Search ..." type="search"/></th>
            <th><input st-search="'course.title'" class="input-sm form-control" placeholder="Search ..." type="search"/></th>           
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr  ng-repeat="quiz in displayedQuizzes">
            <td>{{quiz.title}}</td>
            <td>{{quiz.course.title}}</td>          
        </tr>
    </tbody>   
</table>
```

This is my angular code:

```
angular.module('App')
.controller('ArchiveCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', 'Archive, function ($scope, $window, Archive) {
    $scope.quizzes = Archive.query();   
}]);
```

Comment: Can you show the angular code?

Comment: there is an error in the controller declaration `.controller('ArchiveCtrl', ['$scope', 'Archive, function ($scope, $window, Archive) {` -  you didn't define `$window` as input parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [stacktrace question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431774/angularjs-smart-table-strange-behavior-with-nested-objects-and-st-search)

Nested search is not supported by smart-table.js

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have to wrap the `st-search` value in quotes? the smart tables documentation doesn't use quotes.

http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

```
        <input st-search="firstName" placeholder="search for firstname" class="input-sm form-control" type="search"/>
```

Comment: If I don't, neither the quiz title nor the course.title works. But I have tried every possible combination of quotes and nothing seems to work for the course.title.

Comment: To support you please provide a running plunker.